# Are fasts broken if you don't follow imsak timing?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I just found out that my previous fasts might not be valid but please help me confirm if it's true or not.

Whenever I want to fast, I have suhoor until fajr time. My friend tells me that's wrong and my fast is broken because I didn't follow the imsak time which is approximately 10 minutes because fajr time.

For example: If fajr time is 6:10, then imsak time is 6:00. So I should stop eating and drinking at imsak time.

Is this true? If it is true and I didn't know about it, are my previous fasts valid?

Comment: Are you Sunni or Shia?

Comment: I am Sunni muslim

Comment: In Islam there's no such a thing called imsak time. It could be a precaution for Muslims living in non-Muslim environment, where people may rely on calculation methods which have a certain error tolerance else the true far is the time one must stop eating/drinking and it must be announced by adhan.

Answer (score 2):

You can eat up to the time for true dawn. This is the same as the starting time of fajr as you might find in a correct calendar or app.

> وكلوا واشربوا حتى يتبين لكم الخيط الأبيض من الخيط الأسود من الفجر
>
> And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night].
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:187](https://quran.com/2/187?translations=20)</sup>

> كلوا واشربوا حتى يؤذن ابن أم مكتوم، فإنه لا يؤذن حتى يطلع الفجر
>
> Carry on taking your meals (eat and drink) till Ibn Um Maktum pronounces the Adhan, for he does not pronounce it till it is dawn.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1918)</sup>

Stopping earlier might be suggested by some for safety - i.e. to make sure you are not unknowingly eating when the time is over. However this is not required and your fast is valid.

Comment: As an example of some scholars who recommend a gap of 10 minutes, see [islamonline](https://fiqh.islamonline.net/en/when-a-fasting-person-should-stop-eating/) and [islamqa.org](https://islamqa.org/maliki/seekersguidance-maliki/85213/maliki-view-on-stopping-eating-10-minutes-before-fajr-in-ramadan/).